# Android - filter a listview incomplete

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio, filter

This code to filter a listview is working, but when I delete a character in the EditText, don't return the others itens of the Listview, and when I delete all caracteres clean up the ListView.

Here is my activity :

```
EditText inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            itensAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

    });
```

Here is my Adapter class

```
public class ListaItensAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ItemEstoque> implements Filterable {
private Context context;
private List<ItemEstoque> itens = null;
private List<ItemEstoque> itens_exibicao = null;
Filter f;

public ListaItensAdapter(Context context, List<ItemEstoque> itens) {
    super(context, 0, itens);
    this.itens = itens;
    this.itens_exibicao = itens;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    ItemEstoque item = itens.get(position);

    if (view == null)
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_list_estoque, null);

    TextView textViewNomeProduto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_nome);
    textViewNomeProduto.setText(item.getNomeProduto());
    TextView textViewPreco = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_preco);
    textViewPreco.setText(Float.toString(item.getValorUnitarioProduto()));

    return view;

}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if(f == null) {
        f  = new filtrando();
    }

    return f;
}

private class filtrando extends Filter
{
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
        FilterResults result = new FilterResults();

        if(constraint != null || constraint.toString().length() > 0)
        {
            ArrayList<ItemEstoque> filteredItems = new ArrayList<ItemEstoque>();

            for(int i = 0, l = itens.size(); i < l; i++)
            {
                ItemEstoque m = itens.get(i);
                if(m.getNomeProduto().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString())) {
                    filteredItems.add(m);
                }
            }
            result.count = filteredItems.size();
            result.values = filteredItems;
        }
        else
        {
            synchronized(this)
            {
                result.values = itens;
                result.count = itens.size();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

        itens_exibicao = (ArrayList<ItemEstoque>)results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        clear();
        for(int i = 0, l = itens_exibicao.size(); i < l; i++)
            add(itens_exibicao.get(i));
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        //notifyDataSetInvalidated();

    }
}
```

I have already seen a lot of codes about this and I don`t know what could be...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this using simple filter method, As per give code below...

```
EditText inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            itensAdapter.getfilter(s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

    });
```

Now your Adapter look like this.........

```
public class ListaItensAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ItemEstoque>  {
private Context context;
private List<ItemEstoque> itens = null;
private List<ItemEstoque> itens_exibicao = null;
Filter f;

public ListaItensAdapter(Context context, List<ItemEstoque> itens) {
    super(context, 0, itens);
    this.itens = itens;
   this.itens_exibicao = new ArrayList<ItemEstoque>();
        this.itens_exibicao.addAll(itens);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    ItemEstoque item = itens.get(position);

    if (view == null)
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_list_estoque, null);

    TextView textViewNomeProduto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_nome);
    textViewNomeProduto.setText(item.getNomeProduto());
    TextView textViewPreco = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_preco);
    textViewPreco.setText(Float.toString(item.getValorUnitarioProduto()));

    return view;

}

public void getfilter(String charText) {
charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
itens.clear();
if (charText.length() == 0) {
itens.addAll(itens_exibicao);
}
else
{
for (ItemEstoque m : itens_exibicao)
{
if (m.getNomeProduto().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText))
{
itens.add(m);
}
}
}
notifyDataSetChanged();
}


}
```